# Is there a way to check the maximum method length in C++?

Tags: c++, clang, code-analysis

I'm searching a tool that can check if there is a method in my C++ code thats line length is larger than a maximum I can define. I would like to define a threshold of e.g. 50 lines and if there is a function with e.g. 60 lines, the tool should warn me after analyzing.

I know that there is a functionality like that in checkstyle for java. We are using Clang Format right now to format our C++ code, but I didn't find any functionality like that in Clang Format or any other tool for C++.

Does anyone know a tool like that for C++? Thank you so much :)

Comment: You can read all .cpp files in your folder line by line and check the number of characters. Fstream and filesystem are your friends. It is a little more complicated if you are using UTF-8.

Comment: @akirahinoshiro Why check the number of characters when it's lines they care about? But even without that unnecessary complication, you presume each function has its own file, which is not typically the case (because it's tedious in practice).

Comment: you mean the maximum number of lines and not `line length` which is the number of characters per line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [readability-function-size](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-function-size.html) check of [Clang-Tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) does exactly what you are asking for (and more).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing I can think of is scripting your way through it.

Use e.g ctags to get a list of functions in the file
Use perl/python/awk/grep to split your source file into separate files, one file per function
Simply count the lines of each file, take the maximum length. If you need more details, feed each file into a loc-counter e.g. sloccount to
get more refined information. Use grep again to get the output you are interested in
Another tool that might be of help:

Lazy C++: Is is a code generator that splits files that are very similar to c++ into header and source. If you write you transform your code into a lzz file the generated code includes line counter tags per function. The differences in those numbers would show you how big your functions are